# Logback - append library logs to custom appender

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

In my springboot app I have several scheduled tasks.
In the logback-spring.xml file I created multiple appenders,
so I can log in different files depending on the executing task.
The following logic is applied:

- MyApp-root.log (ROOT-FILE): contains high level logs. All the
  information regarding when each task started, ended and so on.
- MyApp-amazon.log (AMAZON-FILE): logs of the amazon task.
- MyApp-amazon-client.log (AMAZON-CLIENT-FILE): contains logs about the
  communication layer to amazon.
- MyApp-shopify-orders.log (SHOPIFY-ORDER-FILE): logs of the shopify
  task.
- MyApp-shopify-rest-client.log (SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE): contains
  logs about the communication layer to shopify.

To log in the ROOT-FILE I'm using the Lombok @Slf4j annotation.
To log to the other files I'm declaring a logger in the task/client classes (`private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("amazon-client-logger");`)

When the app is executing and I enable the communications libraries logs (org.apache.http, org.apache.http.wire) they are printed in my root file.
How I can append these logs to a custom file (eg. MyApp-shopify-rest-client.log)?

logback-spring.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS_HOME" value="/var/log/myapp"/>

    <!-- use Spring default values -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <springProfile name="development">

        ....

    </springProfile>


    <springProfile name="stage">

        ......

    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="production">

        <!-- Application Loggers -->
        <logger name="com.my.app.myapptest" level="debug"/>

        <!-- Spring security & CAS -->
        <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="warn"/>

        <!-- Network communication (REST) -->
        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="debug"/>
        <logger name="com.fasterxml.jackson" level="debug"/>
        <logger name="org.codehaus.jackson" level="debug"/>

        <!-- HttpClient logging, used by Rest template -->
        <logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug"/>
        <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug"/>

        <!-- SOAP web services -->
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws" level="info"/>

        <!-- Databases -->

        <!-- <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="debug"/> -->

        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="warn"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework.data" level="warn"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework.data.jpa" level="warn"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb" level="warn"/>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn"/> <!-- This shows JPA queryes and parameters -->

        <!--Visualize Hibernate queries-->

        <!--Just enable org.hibernate logging-->
        <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="warn" />
        <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="warn" />

    </springProfile>



    <appender name="ROOT-FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-root.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-root.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1024MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>



    <appender name="AMAZON-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-amazon.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/MyApp-amazon.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1024MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>



    <appender name="SHOPIFY-ORDER-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-shopify-orders.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/MyApp-shopify-orders.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1024MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>



    <appender name="SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-shopify-rest-client.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/MyApp-shopify-rest-client.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1024MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>



    <appender name="AMAZON-CLIENT-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}/MyApp-amazon-client.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/MyApp-amazon-client.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1024MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>



    <logger name="com.my.myapp.myapptest" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ROOT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="amazon-logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AMAZON-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="amazon-client-logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AMAZON-CLIENT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="shopify-orders-logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SHOPIFY-ORDER-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="shopify-rest-client-logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication"
            level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ROOT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>


    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="ROOT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the logger config for the org.apache.http and org.apache.http.wire loggers.

Here is my suggestion

```
    <logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @DwB. 
Doing like this I think I will also get logs from  AMAZON-CLIENT-FILE in SHOPIFY-REST-CLIENT-FILE and the other way around. Right?

Comment: No.  the files are configured via the appender configuration.  My suggestion will only change the apperder target of the org.apache.http and org.apache.http.wire loggers

Comment: Just as an addition: If both shopify-client and amazon-client use e.g. Apache HTTP, you cannot distinguish, from which client the call was made and route the logs accordingly, if that's what you wanted. Although maybe it would be possible to work e.g. with MDC and a custom appender or something like this.

Comment: Hi @dunni. This is exacly what i would like to do.

Comment: As mentioned, maybe with a custom appender this would be possible. However, what i would rather would do (if this is a real productive application that generates revenue) is to just forget about dividing into different files, and use a proper log management system and use e.g. stuff like thread IDs, request IDs etc. in the log statements to group and distinguish log statements